# Как изменить встроенный навбар в SwiftUI

Tags: swift, uikit, swiftui

Как сделать встроенный в **swiftui** навбар выглядящим как показано на изображении снизу. Он похож на обычный .largeTitle navbar, но имеет более маленькую высоту и правая кнопка находится на одной строке с тайтлом.
[image: custom navbar]

Comment: Пожалуйста перепишите этот вопрос на русском языке.

Comment: @ВикторМишустин Исправил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.navigationBarItems(leading: Text("Navigation bar").font(.largeTitle), trailing: Button(action: {}, label: {
Image(systemName: "plus.circle").font(.title)
}))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Думаю так, только осталось поиграться с текстом